# jquery autocomplete - defining the list

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to use a simple autocomplete for a list of users names (~500).

1. I see that it's possible to call to some file (i.e. php,ashx) that contain the requested list.
   what is this file?
   how should look the list?
   where can \i find additional data?
2. Alternativily (my prefered choice) I can use a fixed list in:
   From [devbridge](http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/) code: `lookup: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']`

   or from [jquery-UI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) code:`source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]`.

   but the problem is how to set this array not hardcoded - I tried:
   `var arr1 = ['January', 'Jania','February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];
   var arr2 = [];
       for(var i=0;i<all_analysts.length;i++){
           arr[i] = all_analysts[i];
           alert(arr[i]);////////
       }
   lookup: arr2 //local lookup values`

   but only when using hardcoded:`lookup: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']`
   it works.

Can you please assist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As to your **first** question - take a look at this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

As you can see, if *source* option is a string it is treated as url to which the ajax request will be made in order to get the list of data matching term inputed by user. Given url should return data in [JSON format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

If, for example, you would set source option to "/find_users". Once the user would input string "mo" into the input field, the autocomplete widget, would make an ajax request to following url: "/find_users?term=mo". Once the user input another letter (let's say its "r"), another request would be made to url: "/find_users?term=mor".

Notice the *term* query variable that contains current value inputed by user on your page.

As to **second** question - there's typo in your code - you're (for reason which is unclear to me) putting values from array all_analysts into the *arr* variable and then set **arr2** as *lookup* parameter value. In your example *arr2* is an empty array so autocomplete isn't working as expected...